# Projection Operator and Perpendicularity

Tags: functional-analysis, projection

$M\neq \emptyset$ including $M^\bot=\{x \in X\mid x \bot M \}$ is a vector space show that? And it is closed show that?

How can i do show that?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange.com! Please show your attempt on this question so that the community can help you solve this question :)

Comment: I showed that there is a vector space, but I want to be sure. I did not know how to show its closedness.

Comment: Are you working in a Hilbert space?

Comment: Yes, that's true.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understood your question but if you want to show that $M^{\perp}$ is closed just take $x$ in its closure, and so you will have $x_n\rightarrow x$ where $x_n \in M^{\perp}$ and so $\langle x_n,m\rangle =0$ for every $n$ and $m\in M$, and then using the fact the inner product is continuous you get that
$\langle x,m\rangle =\langle\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}x_n,m\rangle=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\langle x_n,m\rangle =0$, and so $x\in M^{\perp}$ and the set is closed.

I assumed you are working with an Hilbert space but if you are using the definition of $\perp$ for a Banach space the idea is the same.

Comment: Use \langle and \rangle for inner product brackets, not < and >.

Comment: Was not aware of that command, Thanks.